# How to remove environmentObject after dismiss View

Tags: swiftui, uikit, environmentobject

I have a View like this:

```
    struct MainView: View{
    @EnvironmentObject var appModel: AppDataModel
    @State var localAppDataModel: AppDataModel! = AppDataModel()
    var body: some View{
        VStack {
            ContentView()
    }
         Button(action: {
            appModel.dismissAR()
        },
               label: {
            Text(LocalizedString.close)
                .modifier(VisualEffectRoundedCorner())
        })
        .environmentObject(localAppDataModel)
        .onDisappear{
            localAppDataModel.objectCaptureSession?.cancel()
            localAppDataModel.photogrammetrySession?.cancel()
            localAppDataModel.objectCaptureSession = nil
            localAppDataModel.photogrammetrySession = nil
            localAppDataModel.scanFolderManager = nil
            localAppDataModel.showPreviewModel = false
            localAppDataModel.orbit = .orbit1
            localAppDataModel.orbitState = .initial
            localAppDataModel.isObjectFlipped = false
            localAppDataModel = nil
        }
    }
```

I present this view in `UIKIt` with this func:

```
public static func present(viewC: UIViewController){
    let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: MainView(appModel: .init()))
    mainController = controller
    mainController?.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    guard let mainController else { return }
    viewC.present(mainController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
var mainController: UIHostingController<MainView>?
```

When I dismiss

> MainView

```
public class AppDataModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
....
    func dismissAR(){
        mainController?.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
....
   }
```

my app crash because `localAppDataModel` become `nil`. How can I dismiss MainView and deallocate/remove localdaAppDataModel environmentObject?

Comment: "When I dismiss"  How are you dismissing it at what line?

Comment: Have you tried using `@StateObject var localAppDataModel = AppDataModel()`, without the silly `!`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a `ObservableObject` you can use `@StateObject var model = AppDataModel()` which will init it once and deinit it on disappear automatically, including clearing all of its properties.

FYI if you decide to upgrade from Combine's `ObservableObject` to use `@Observable` then you need to make an optional `@State var model: AppDataModel?` and init it yourself in `onAppear` and set it nil in `onDisappear`. Bit more effort but you get tighter invalidation of your Views since it can track the object's individual properties rather that the whole object.